# The font weight of output pdf plots from Mathematica 11.3

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I am using Mathematica for plotting. The current version is 11.3. When I output vector figures such as .pdf and .eps formats, the font weight of the tick labels and text become bold, even though I set as plain text. Does anybody have the same problem? Could you help me to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are on Mac OS Mojave then this is a known bug. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/183053/58370) for workarounds.

Comment: Okay, I do see now this is a known bug for Mathematica on Mac OS Mojave. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Update: problem solved if your Mathematica is upgraded to, for example, version 12.1.1.0